# linecast always returns true

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a linecast to avoid my enemy to fall off the map and getting stuck on walls, if he detects an edge or wall, he flips and start moving the other way. The linecast to detect edges is doing just fine, however the linecast facing left (to detect walls), is always getting triggered and i dont know why, so the enemy just keeps flipping every frame.

My script:

```
public class Enemy1 : MonoBehaviour {

Rigidbody2D myBody;
Transform myTransf;
public LayerMask enemyMask;

float myWidth;
public float speed;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    myTransf = this.transform;
    myBody = this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    myWidth = this.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().bounds.extents.x;

}

// Update is called once per frame
void FixedUpdate () {
    // checking if theres any walls or edges, if so, flip
    Vector2 lineCastPos = myTransf.position - myTransf.right * myWidth;
    Debug.DrawLine(lineCastPos, lineCastPos + Vector2.down);
    bool isGrounded = Physics2D.Linecast(lineCastPos, lineCastPos + Vector2.down, enemyMask);
    Debug.DrawLine(lineCastPos, lineCastPos - myTransf.right.toVector2() *0.1f);
    bool isBlocked = Physics2D.Linecast(lineCastPos, lineCastPos - myTransf.right.toVector2() * 0.1f, enemyMask);
    RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Linecast(lineCastPos, lineCastPos - myTransf.right.toVector2());

    if (!isGrounded || !isBlocked)
        {
        Vector3 currRot = myTransf.eulerAngles;
        currRot.y += 180;
        myTransf.eulerAngles = currRot;
        Debug.Log("Ray Hit: " + hit.point);
    }

    //moving left always
    Vector2 myVel = myBody.velocity;
    myVel.x = -myTransf.right.x * speed;
    myBody.velocity = myVel;

}
```

}

Note: The RayCastHit2D Log gives me the point 0.0, 0.0 (highlighted in the red dot in my screenshot) and nothing is sitting there, only the main camera.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2RvW.jpg)

Comment: Sorry if that's not the issue, but that `if (!isGrounded || !isBlocked)` looks suspicious to me: do you mean `if (!isGrounded && !isBlocked)` ?

Comment: I changed to && and the issue still persists, thanks for the input anyways ^^